# iMessage sharing and changing AppleID

Tags: security, messages, apple-id, privacy

My husband and I recently split up. Both our phones and both our iPads were all on his Apple ID. Would I be notified on my phone if he were checking my iMessages? I have recently created my own Apple ID and changed my phone and iPad to that. Would that be enough to ensure he cannot access my messages and information? I'm asking because he had said he was able to read my messages if he wanted to but I would be notified

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature to allow someone to sign in to a second Apple ID, so unless he guessed your new Apple ID and new password, he's not receiving your messages.

You could enable two factor authentication to ensure no one easily signs in as you. There are forensic and legal ways to read people's messages - but they are generally complicated or costly.

Most of this is explained at https://appleid.apple.com and if there is something specific you don't get - you can ask a new question more narrowly focusing on one aspect of privacy since the site works best with one question per question.

In summary, unless your husband (or ex) has installed key logging software on a computer, you should be able to prevent them from receiving any messages for you by changing your Apple ID password and making sure the phone company has a separate account for your devices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That helps. Before I changed my Apple ID, all devices were sharing his Apple ID. Would I have been notified on my device if he had added my number to his iMessage receipts on either his phone or iPad? I have nothing to hide, but I am concerned that he was reading my previous messages without my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if he had your AppleID and password, and tried to log into iMessage with it, your phone will pop up with a notification that says that a new device has connected to your imessage. This is what I got when I synced my new iPad with my imessage account.